# How can I get a larger profile image from facebook

Tags: supabase, facebook-authentication

I'm using Supabase in a React Native project with Expo.  I'm using the Facebook auth provider.  I can login and I get a JWT.  If I decode the JWT I see an "avatar_url" field with a url to the profile image, but it is only 50x50 pixels.  How can I get a larger image.  If I simply change the width and height in the returned url, it doesn't work.

Here is the code in my fucntion:

```
async function login() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: 'facebook',
    })
    if(data?.url) {
      let result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(data.url, Linking.createURL())
      if(result.type == 'success') {
        const access_token = result.url.split('#')[1].split('&')[0].replace('access_token=', '')
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync('access_token', access_token)
      }
      console.log(result)
      console.log(await SecureStore.getItemAsync('access_token'))
      console.log(await supabase.auth.getUser(await SecureStore.getItemAsync('access_token')))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `avatar_url` returns small image 50x50 pixels. If you want larger image you should include `picture` field in your request to the `Graph API` as following:

`Part 1:`

```
import{createClient} from '@supabase/supabase-js';
const supabase = createClient('https://sample_url.supabase.co', 'supabase_key');
const{user} = await supabase.auth.signInWithProvider({
              provider: 'facebook');
const{data: {url}} = await supabase.from('profiles').select(
            'avatar_url, picture').eq('id', user.id).single();
const avatarUrl = url.replace('50x50', '200x200');
```

`Part 2:`

```
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';

async function login() {
  const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('YOUR_APP_ID', {
    permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],});
      if (type === 'success') {
    const { user } = await supabase.auth.signIn({provider: 'facebook',
      accessToken: token,});
    const profileResponse = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${user.id}/picture?type=large&access_token=${token}`);
    const profileUrl = profileResponse.url;
    console.log(profileUrl); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're calling the Graph api?  I also don't understand supabase.from('profiles')...  I don't have a profiles table anywhere.  And the function I'm using to authenticate is singInWithOauth.

Comment: It's just a sample, share your code for further discussion

Comment: code added to my original question

Comment: got your code, and updated my answer with `Part 2`. Please try and let me know the result